# How to call a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I create prepared statement for sql that give me the right result in *mysqlWorkbench*, but when I tried to use the same query with **php pdo**, it returns me an *empty Array*.

So how to use my prepared statement with **php pdo** ?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');


$pstmt = "set @sql = null;
            select 
              group_concat(distinct
                 concat(
                     'MAX(IF(ch.ch_name = ''', replace(ch.ch_name, '''', '\''''), ''', v.v_value, NULL)) AS ''', replace(ch.ch_name, '''', ' ') , ''''
                 )
            ) into @sql
            FROM e_champ ch
            join e_champ_value v on v.v_fk_champ_id = ch.ch_id
            join e_collecte c on c.c_id = v.v_fk_collecte_id
            AND c.c_id = 2;

            set @sql = concat('select oi.oi_id, ', @sql, ' from e_order_item oi 
                  left join e_champ_value v on v.v_fk_order_item_id = oi.oi_id
                  join e_champ ch on ch.ch_id = v.v_fk_champ_id
                  join e_collecte c on c.c_id = v.v_fk_collecte_id
                  AND c.c_id = 2 GROUP BY oi_id');

            PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;"; 


$sth = $dbh->prepare($pstmt);
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);


?>
```

Comment: Not sure if preparing something that's being prepared makes much sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution that give me the right result.

I create a stored procedure in the database then I call it within php pdo.

```
 DELIMITER $$
     
    
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetResult()
    BEGIN
    
    set @sql = null;
                select 
                  group_concat(distinct
                     concat(
                         'MAX(IF(ch.ch_name = ''', replace(ch.ch_name, '''', '\''''), ''', v.v_value, NULL)) AS ''', replace(ch.ch_name, '''', ' ') , ''''
                     )
                ) into @sql
                FROM e_champ ch
                join e_champ_value v on v.v_fk_champ_id = ch.ch_id
                join e_collecte c on c.c_id = v.v_fk_collecte_id
                AND c.c_id = 2;
    
                set @sql = concat('select oi.oi_id, ', @sql, ' from e_order_item oi 
                      left join e_champ_value v on v.v_fk_order_item_id = oi.oi_id
                      join e_champ ch on ch.ch_id = v.v_fk_champ_id
                      join e_collecte c on c.c_id = v.v_fk_collecte_id
                      AND c.c_id = 2 GROUP BY oi_id');
    
                PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    END$$
```

// PHP code

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');


$pstmt = "call GetResult()"; 


$sth = $dbh->prepare($pstmt);
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);

?>
```

This is a link about php preapared statement and stored procedures https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Your "prepared" statement is prone to SQL injection.

Because you are not preparing your query for real, but just imitating a prepared statement, while in reality using the same old dirty concatenation and manual escaping.

And as a result, there is not a single reason to use SQL prepared statement in your case.

Anyway, to answer the question from the title, to run *any* sql query, be it with SQL prepared statements or without, you have to use `query()` method, **running separate SQL queries in separate `query()` calls.**

Comment: Does the solution that I have given is prone to SQL injection ? If yes, how to modifiy the code so ?

Comment: Yes, it is prone. It's hard to tell because you are using a database unnatural way

Answer (score -2):

See if this helps:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tabela_nome','user','pass');

try{
    $select= "SELECT * from user_ WHERE email=:'email@email.com'";
    $result = $conn->prepare($select);
    $result->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e){       
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```